# Quick Query (Fall, Spring)

Tags: sql, record

How do I get records of a table that have column a with id, column b value = 'Fall' or column b value = 'Spring' but not both?

Thanks.

Comment: How can column a have both values 'Fall' *and* 'Spring'?

Comment: Okay so let's say the records in the table are... 1 'Fall' 2 'Spring' 2 'Fall'  I only want 1 'Fall'

Comment: Your definition is very vague, and changes with every revision. Also, which SQL engine are you talking about, the Microsoft SQL?

Comment: I also updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

For Updated Question
If for only Fall and String values

```
Select * from atablename where b in ('fall', 'spring') group by a having count(a) = 1
```

for any values

```
Select * from atablename group by a having count(a) = 1
```

For Old Question

```
Select * from atablename where (a = 'Fall' AND b != 'Spring') OR (a != 'Fall' AND b = 'Spring')
```

Comment: Ohhh, sorry I have a error in the question. Let me correct it.

Comment: You might want to change 'Fail' to 'Fall' ...

Comment: Thanks Scott, Updated :)

Comment: Your updated query gives me the following output, 1 'Fall' 1 'Spring' 2'Fall' 3'Fall' instead it should only give 2'Fall' and 3'Fall'

Comment: You should clearly mentioned that you want like this. Please update question properly.

Comment: Can you update your query?

Comment: @SohelMansuri we kinda assumed your rows were not implicitly grouped by some column you hadn't mentioned.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, yes, sorry.

Comment: @SohelMansuri try updated query now

Comment: @SohelMansuri  Select * from atablename group by a having count(a) == 1

Comment: @MaulikVora I'f afraid you can't assume there will be no other values other than `Fall` and `Spring`

Comment: @JanDvorak I think, Sohel is not explaining what you want, but I am sure he will have clear requirement like this and If not, he should try  Select * from atablename  where b in ('fall', 'spring') group by a having count(a) == 1

Comment: @MaulikVora nice fix ;-) suggest that in the answer

Answer (score 1):

For the original question:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM your_table t
WHERE ((t.a = 'Fall' AND t.b != 'Spring') OR (t.a != 'Fall' AND t.b = 'Spring'))
```

Should do the trick

For the new one,

```
SELECT
    t.a
    , t.b
FROM your_table t
WHERE ((t.b = 'Fall' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourtable t1 WHERE t1.a = t.a AND t1.b = 'Spring'))
    OR (t.b = 'Spring' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourtable t1 WHERE t1.a = t.a AND t1.b = 'Fall')))
```

Should work

Comment: I made a mistake in the question, please look at it again.